# Smooth LSTM predictions

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, prediction

I am new to deep learning models. This is my first post, so please do let me know if there are any additional details that you may need.

Here is a general summary of my approach:

- I used a dataset having **two** time series for training
- I converted them to the dataset accepted by keras' LSTM/Bi-LSTM layers in the format: 
  [1, 0.99, 0.98, 0.97] ==Output==> [0.96] 
  and so on..
- Shapes of the input and output containers (arrays): input(794, 5, 1) and output(794, )
- Error-free training
- Prediction on an initial points of data (window) having shape (1, 5, 1)
- The predicted output is a value, which is appended to a separate list (for plotting), as well as appended to the window, and the first value of the window dropped out. This window is then fed as input to the model to generate the next prediction point.
- Continue this until I get the whole curve for both models (LSTM and Bi-LSTM)

However, the prediction is not even close to the actual data.

[Obtained curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIFoO.png)

With some changes in the batch sizes and other parameters, I am still able to get the TREND (downwards in this case), but not the SHAPE of the data (edges, in-between variations, absolutely nothing).

Is it because of using only two time series for training? I cannot exactly figure out the problem.

Model (similar code goes for Bi-LSTM model):

```
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(timesteps, 1), return_sequences= True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.1))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences= True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.1))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences= False))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.1))
model_lstm.add(Dense(1))
model_lstm.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizers.Adam(0.001))
```

Curve prediction code:

```
timesteps = 5
start = cell_to_test[0:timesteps].reshape(1, timesteps, 1)   # Has the initial data points
yhat = 1.0
y_curve_lstm = list(start.flatten())                         # The list for storing the curve points
y_window = start                                             # Window
```

The loop to predict the individual points until a limit is reached: (The limits of the cell data whose curve I am predicting):

```
while len(y_curve_lstm) <= len(cell_to_test):
  yhat = model_lstm.predict(y_window)
  yhat = float(yhat)
  y_curve_lstm.append(yhat)
  y_window = list(y_window.flatten())
  y_window.append(yhat)
  y_window.remove(y_window[0])
  y_window = np.array(y_window).reshape(1, timesteps, 1)
  #print(yhat)
```

Comment: You've got a model with a lot of parameters there (try `model_lstm.summary()`). A lot of parameters requires a lot of training data. I suggest trying a much smaller model first. In addition, if the variations are due to factors that aren't in the data, even the best model will never be able to predict them, as the information just isn't in the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Swier. I tried to simplify the model by using just one layer and increasing the neurons from 2 to 128, but the smoothness always follows, and does not give a clear trend. Also, in the image above, the 'actual' refers to the data, which clearly shows a peak in the middle of the curve, so it wasn't clear with what you meant by the phrase 'if the variations are due to factors that aren't in the data'.

Comment: I read your question again and realize that I misread it the first time. You only have 2 training examples (right?), which is not nearly enough, you'll need thousands before an LSTM starts being useful. If you want to try deep learning, I suggest finding another dataset (have a look at kaggle.com for example), if you want to solve this problem, you'll need more data and you'll probably want to use a much simpler model (have a look at sktime.org).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight. I'll use more data and check if it provides better results (I wanted to initially test with lesser and smaller datasets to see if it works okay).